# How to set environment variables by calling a tcsh script that sources another csh script

Tags: tcsh, csh

I'm unable to set environmental variables present in a `.csh` using another `.tcsh` that is sourcing this file inside it:

- This does not set the environment variables:

  ```
  $PERC_PATH/bin/runperc.csh ...<some arguments>
  ```
- Whereas this does set the environment variables:

  ```
  source $PERC_PATH/bin/runperc.csh ..<some arguments>
  ```

Both are executable, shebangs are `/usr/bin/csh`, and `runperc.csh` sources `perc_setup.csh` within it:

```
source $PERC_PATH/perc_setup.csh
```

- `perc_setup.csh` contains `setenv` and some other commands:

  ```
  setenv MGC_RVEDB_DIR {$PERC_PATH}/setup:{$HOME}
  ```

How do I set the environment variables in the terminal without having to explicitly `source`  the script path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables can never propagate "upwards" from an external executable into the shell. If they need to be set by a csh script, then you *have to* `source` that script – hide the 'source' behind an alias if you want.

```
alias perc 'source $PERC_PATH/bin/runperc.csh'
```

There are some alternatives – e.g. making the script output environment variables to stdout to be eval'd by the parent – but they would be even more verbose and would still require you to run code directly in the parent shell.